Error loading config: Requested templater 'dbt' which is not currently available. Try one of raw, jinja, python, placeholder
Need to understand that what is causing the issue in the pre-commit hook section of sqlfluff
Although  sqlfluff-templater-dbt is installed sqlfluff is installed, but gets and error that templater 'dbt' is not currently available.
here are my sqlfluff and recommit hook files
pre-commit run sqlfluff-lint
sqlfluff-lint............................................................Failed
- hook id: sqlfluff-lint
- exit code: 2

Starting in sqlfluff version 0.7.0 the dbt templater is distributed as a separate python package. Please pip install sqlfluff-templater-dbt to use it.
Error loading config: Requested templater 'dbt' which is not currently available. Try one of raw, jinja, python, placeholder

#.sqlfluff


[sqlfluff]

# Supported dialects https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/dialects.html
# Or run 'sqlfluff dialects'
dialect = postgres

# One of [raw|jinja|python|placeholder]
templater = dbt
sql_file_exts = .sql,.sql.j2,.dml,.ddl

# Comma separated list of rules to exclude, or None
# See https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#enabling-and-disabling-rules
# AM04 (ambiguous.column_count) and ST06 (structure.column_order) are
# two of the more controversial rules included to illustrate usage.
exclude_rules = ambiguous.column_count, structure.column_order

# The standard max_line_length is 80 in line with the convention of
# other tools and several style guides. Many projects however prefer
# something a little longer.
# Set to zero or negative to disable checks.
max_line_length = 140

# CPU processes to use while linting.
# The default is "single threaded" to allow easy debugging, but this
# is often undesirable at scale.
# If positive, just implies number of processes.
# If negative or zero, implies number_of_cpus - specified_number.
# e.g. -1 means use all processors but one. 0 means all cpus.
processes = 0

# If using the dbt templater, we recommend setting the project dir.
[sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
project_dir = ./
profiles_dir = .dbt/
profile = my_transformation
target = prod

[sqlfluff:templater:jinja]
apply_dbt_builtins = True

#.pre-commit-config.yaml

repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
    rev: 3.0.7  # Use the version you want
    hooks:
      - id: sqlfluff-lint
        name: SQLFluff lint
        entry: sqlfluff lint
        language: python
        files: \.sql$
      - id: sqlfluff-fix
        name: SQLFluff fix
        entry: sqlfluff fix
        language: python
        files: \.sql$

      

why it says
Error loading config: Requested templater 'dbt' which is not currently available. Try one of raw, jinja, python, placeholder
but when running
sqlfluff lint my_sql_file.sql 

or
sqlfluff fix my_sql_file.sql 

it works fine, please explain what is the issue is in the pre-commit hook section

pre-commit installs tools in isolated environments (not your environment!) to avoid interfering with your projects
in this case it is installing sqlfluff to its own isolated environment, so your sqlfluff command you're running is unrelated to the one it runs
in order to use dbt you'll want to follow the docs for sqlfluff to configure additional_dependencies to install whatever ancillary sqlfluff plugins you need (like the one for dbt!)

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit
